# Rebuild/recreate terraform from remote state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

A contractor built an application's AWS infrastructure on his local laptop, never commited his code then left (wiping the notebook's HD). But he did create the infrastructure with Terraform and stored the remote state in an s3 bucket, s3://analytics-nonprod/analytics-dev.tfstate.

This state file includes all of the VPC, subnets, igw, nacl, ec2, ecs, sqs, sns, lambda, firehose, kinesis, redshift, neptune, glue connections, glue jobs, alb, route53, s3, etc. for the application.

I am able to run Cloudformer to generate cloudformation for the entire infrastructure, and also tried to import the infrastructure using terraformer but terraformer does not include neptune and lambda components.

What is the best way/process to recreate a somewhat usable terraform just from the remote state?
Should I generate some generic :
resource "aws_glue_connection" "dev" { }
and run "terraform import  aws_glue_connection.dev"
then run "terraform show"

for each resource?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn't have a mechanism specifically for turning existing state into configuration, and indeed doing so would be lossy in the general case because the Terraform configuration likely contained expressions connecting resources to one another that are not captured in the state snapshots.

However, you might be able to get a starting point -- possibly not 100% valid but hopefully a better starting point than nothing at all -- by configuring Terraform just enough to find the remote state you have access to, running `terraform init` to make Terraform read it, and then run `terraform show` to see the information from the state in a human-oriented way that is designed to resemble (but not necessarily *exactly* match) the configuration language.

For example, you could write a backend configuration like this:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "analytics-nonprod"
    key    = "analytics-dev.tfstate"
  }
}
```

If you run `terraform init` with appropriate AWS credentials available then Terraform should read that state snapshot, install the providers that the resource instances within it belong to, and then leave you in a situation where you can run Terraform commands against that existing state. As long as you don't take any actions that *modify* the state, you should be able to inspect it with commands like `terraform show`.

You could then copy the `terraform show` output into another file in your new Terraform codebase as a starting point. The output is aimed at human consumption and is not necessarily all parsable by Terraform itself, but the output style is similar enough to the configuration language that hopefully it won't take too much effort to massage it into a usable shape.

One important detail to watch out for is the handling of Terraform modules. If the configuration that produced this state contained any `module "foo"` blocks then in your `terraform show` output you will see some things like this:

```
# module.foo.aws_instance.bar
resource "aws_instance" "bar" {
  # ...
}
```

In order to replicate the configuration for that, it is not sufficient to paste the entire output into one file. Instead, any resource block that has a comment above it indicating that it belongs to a module will need to be placed in a configuration file belonging to that module, or else Terraform will not understand that block as relating to the object it can see in the state.

---

I'd strongly suggest taking a backup copy of the state object you have before you begin, and you should be very careful not to apply any plans while you're in this odd state of having only a backend configuration, because Terraform might (if it's able to pick up enough provider configuration from the execution environment) plan to destroy all of the objects in the state in order to match the configuration.